# How to get text from page? Selenium, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

```
 [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Arrange
            String expected = "text";

            //a ACT
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&hl=pl#identifier");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='Email']"));
            email.Clear();
            email.SendKeys("myemail");

            IWebElement buttonElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='next']"));
            buttonElement.Click();

            var wait1 = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            var password = wait1.Until(wd => wd.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='Passwd']")));            
            password.Clear();
            password.SendKeys("mypassword");

            IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='signIn']"));
            login.Click();

            expected = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("z0")).Text; //<-DOES'NT WORK


            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(expected.Contains("text"));

        }
    }
```

Hello. I made test to log on the gmail. But i want to find text on this page after log in, and put it to "assert" at the end of my test. 
Could you help me, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *wait for the element to be present*:

```
var expected = wait1.Until(wd => wd.FindElement(By.ClassName("z0"))).Text;
```